# unable to import excel 2007 to sql server using openrowset function

Tags: openrowset

I want to import records in excel 2007  to sql server 2005 table. I used the query following query to select the reocrds.

```
select * 
FROM OPENROWSET ('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' ,'Excel 12.0;Database=d:\input.xlsx' ,
                 'SELECT * FROM [a$]' )
```

The query is running long time without any error or result. Then I convert the file to .xls format and used the following query.

```
select * 
FROM OPENROWSET ('Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0' , 'Excel 8.0;Database=d:\input.xls' ,
                 'SELECT * FROM [a$]' )
```

It displayed the records.

But in most of the scenario, I should use .xlsx extension. Because the no. of records in a sheet may be huge.

Please help me.

Thanks, 
P.Gopalakrishnan

Comment: I restarted the server and tried again the same queries in same order as given above. Now there is no problem with the driver Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0. But when executing the second query I am getting the error "Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" for linked server "(null)"

Answer (score 0):

Go to ServerObjects Then LinedServers Then Providers 
If the name of the Provieder is not in the List then 
It will Give Error Of Provider.